# Printing Panel Containing RichTextBox and Pictures window form

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

Hello friends I am facing problem in printing `Panel(PanelContain)` containing `RichTextBox(RichtxtHospName ,RichTxtPatDetail ,RichTxtRptBody )` and pictures,here all controls are dynamically created.When I am printing `panel(PanelContain)` it only print pictures but not text in text box.

> Define My controls

```
 RichTextBox RichtxtHospName = new RichTextBox();
        RichTextBox RichTxtPatDetail = new RichTextBox();
        RichTextBox RichTxtRptBody = new RichTextBox();
        Panel PanelContain = new Panel();
```

> My code for printing Panel

```
 private void PrintPanel()
        {
            System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
            doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(doc_PrintPage);
            doc.Print();
        }
 private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(PanelContain.Width, PanelContain.Height+30);
                float tgtWidthMM = 210;  //A4 paper size
                float tgtHeightMM = 297;
                float tgtWidthInches = tgtWidthMM / 25.4f;
                float tgtHeightInches = tgtHeightMM / 25.4f;
                float srcWidthPx = bmp.Width;
                float srcHeightPx = bmp.Height;
                float dpiX = srcWidthPx / tgtWidthInches;
                float dpiY = srcHeightPx / tgtHeightInches;
                bmp.SetResolution(dpiX, dpiY);
                PanelContain.DrawToBitmap(bmp, PanelContain.ClientRectangle);
                e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, tgtWidthMM, tgtHeightMM);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }


 private void toolStripBtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
                doc.PrintPage += this.doc_PrintPage;
                PrintDialog dlgSettings = new PrintDialog();
                dlgSettings.Document = doc;
                if (dlgSettings.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    PrintPanel();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: RichTextBox doesnt support the `DrawToBitmap` method, which is called by your `PanelContain.DrawToBitmap` call. Here is a MSDN link with more info including a `CopyFromScreen` workaround: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1454d078-c312-4741-88df-aa7eb306fe51/how-to-save-the-content-of-richtextbox-as-jpg-file?forum=winforms

Comment: You might also read somewhere (even here) that the new `RICHEDIT50W` class supports it. Doesn't happen.